# Typo3 Extension Manager does´t work

Tags: php, typo3, root

i installed Typo3 (6.1) on my root server. When i want to get a Extension in the Extension Manager, it shows me a empty (grey) Page.( With all Navigation Parts of the Typo3 BE) No Error, nothing! Maybe a wrong php.ini or curl.ini configuration?

Comment: Probably a php-error. What does the server error log say about that?

Answer (score 0):

Its the Maximum function nesting Level of php. Turn it up to 500 and it will help. Sometimes u only see this

Comment: Consider adding the `php.ini` statement to actually make it work; that would make your answer much more valuable.